# How to Download part of Library in my Android app from Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have imported to my build.gradle, google play services library

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1.
```

But this downloads all the library resulting to a 20mb app. I want to download only what i need. In this case the barcode api for qr codes. How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google separated google-play-services library into several parts, so not nesessary to use full library.
For barcode API you need

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0

All parts of Google Play Services library are listed here:

[Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)